# how to get largest number in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I had a table named 'userinf' in mysql containing account number (acno) which is auto_incrementing  to retrieve largest  of acno i used the below command.

```
qr="select MAX('acno') from 'userinf' ";

$EX=mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

$ex=mysql_fetch_ARRAY($EX);

echo "$ex";
```

and want iam getting is the name of the column i.e acno but not maximum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Change the query, removing quotes:

```
qr="select MAX(acno) from userinf";
```

Field names are quoted, using backqoutes: ` in MySQL, not straight quotes, that you use. But you don't need it here.

2.Remember, that you are receiving the array, so you must use an index:

```
echo "$ex[0]";
```

Comment: for echo "$ex[0]"; also getting same output as acno

Comment: @Rathan Did you remove the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

```
qr="select MAX('acno') from 'userinf' ";

$EX=mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

$ex=mysql_fetch_ARRAY($EX);

echo "$ex";
```

should be like this

```
$qr="select MAX('acno') as acno from 'userinf' ";

$EX=mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

$ex=mysql_fetch_array($EX);

echo $ex['acno'];

or 
echo $ex[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 `echo $ex[0]`
```

or you can use

```
`echo $ex['max_acc_no']`
```

if you use

```
`select MAX('acno') max_acc_no from 'userinf'`
```

as the query

Answer (score 1):

```
$ex=mysql_fetch_ARRAY($EX);

echo "$ex"
```

should be

```
$ex=mysql_fetch_array($EX);

echo $ex[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
qr="select MAX(`acno`) as acn from `userinf` ";

$EX=mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

$ex=mysql_fetch_ARRAY($EX);

echo $ex['acn'];
```

Do not use single quote`'` use back tick ` it is near by tab button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list($ex) = mysql_fetch_num($EX);
echo $ex;
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

mysql_fetch_ARRAY returns array of result...

```
qr="select MAX(acno) as acn from userinf ";

$EX=mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

$ex=mysql_fetch_ARRAY($EX);

echo $ex[0];
```